# Display my logo correctly in React Native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, react-redux

I'm starting the ReacNative study, and I bought a ready template.

I'm having trouble getting my rectangular and horizontal logitopes to display correctly on the login screen.
The logo is displayed square, I have already tested various adjustments in Style.js, the 'logoImage' and 'logo' tags of the style file, but without success.

What style setting should I make for my logo to be displayed correctly?

Follow my repository:
https://github.com/tmacedo2014/appLoginReact

The page in question is in:
appLoginReact / src / Screen / Member / SignIn / index.js

My rectangular logo is in:
appLoginReact/assets/images/logo@2x.png
[print of login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bi11.jpg)

Comment: Hard to say without being able to see the output html and css, but this is mostly a css question. You should use your [inspector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/) to view the styles being applied to your image and then [add new styles](https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822) to get it to look like you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit some styles. First try this and let me know if it helped.

in the path `src/Screen/Member/SignIn/index.js` go to line **117** and overwrite it as following.

```
 <Image  style={{resizeMode: 'contain'}} source={require('@Asset/images/logo@2x.png')} />
```